# Accessing public methods of a Private Inner Class, from outside the Enclosing class

Tags: java, private, inner-classes

I have the following code class Agent.java :

```
 public class Agent {
      Helper helper ;

      private class SpecificBehaviour extends Behaviour{
         private Apple a;
         public SpecificBehaviour(Apple a){
          setApple(a);
          }
          public void setApple(Apple a){
           this.a=a;
          }
          public Apple getApple(){
          return a;
          }
         } 

         public void someMethod(){
         helper = new Helper(this);
        }   

}
```

In the Helper.java ( another class  within the same package) I would like to access the getApple() method. did some search and found this  [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/394730/java/java/public-method-private-class)
 I am wondering if there is a better/ easier way of doing this ?

Comment: Simply OuterClass.InnerClass innerClass = new OuterClass.new InnerClass();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two issues here:

- `Helper` doesn't know of the existence of `SpecificBehaviour`, because it's a private class. It *could* potentially know about the `Behaviour` class, which you haven't given any details of. If `getApple()` is declared in `Behaviour`, and if `Behaviour` is visible to `Helper`, then the visibility part needn't be a problem.
- `Helper` will need a reference to an instance of `SpecificBehaviour`, which means you'll need to instantiate `SpecificBehaviour`. For that, you'll also need an instance of `Agent`, because `SpecificBehaviour` is an *inner class*. It's not clear whether you *have* such an instance.

Basically I think the presence of a private inner class is adding confusion here. If you're reasonably new to Java, I'd strongly recommend sticking to top-level classes for the moment. They have a few subtleties around them, and it's best to try to learn one thing at a time.

If this doesn't help, please give more context - your question is quite vague at the moment. *Where* do you want to use `getApple` within `Helper`? Should part of the state of `Helper` be a reference to an instance of `SpecificBehaviour`, or should it be a method parameter? Have you created an instance of `Agent`? What does `Behaviour` look like? You may find that in the course of answering these questions one at a time, you're better able to figure out the problem for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `Composition` principle to get the access to the `getApple()` method.

**Eg:**

```
public class Agent {

      Apple a = new Apple();     // Agent class has a reference of type Apple.

     .....
     .....
 }
```

**-** Second way would be to make the `getApple()` method `static` in **Apple class**, and then access it from **Agent class** using the Class name with `.` (dot) operator.

**Eg:**

```
  public class Agent {

          public void go(){

            Apple.getApple();

        }

         .....
         .....
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the `Agent` object you are passing to the `Helper` for the **instance** of the private class `SpecificBehaviour`. This is the way it works. Encapsulation remember.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet stated that and I completely agree on it:

> Helper will need a reference to an instance of `SpecificBehaviour`,
>   which means you'll need to instantiate `SpecificBehaviour`. For that,
>   you'll also need an instance of `Agent`, because `SpecificBehaviour` is an
>   inner class. It's not clear whether you have such an instance.

Actually, you can understand how weird your try is by testing the sample code below:

**Agent.java**

```
public class Agent 
{
    private class SpecificBehaviour 
    {
        public String toString()
        {
            return "specific behaviour";
        }
    }
    public Class getInner() 
    {
        return SpecificBehaviour.class;
    }
}
```

**Helper.java**

```
public class Helper 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Agent agent = new Agent();
            System.out.println(agent.getInner().newInstance().toString());
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }
    }
}
```

The code above just compiles fine. And let's see what the output is:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: Agent$SpecificBehaviour
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at Helper.main(Helper.java:5)
```